# Do parentheses in a class definition do anything?

Tags: python

I accidentally included parentheses in my class definition:

```
class Crawler():
    # ...
```

It seems like I'm supposed to do this:

```
class Crawler:
    # ...
```

Do those erroneous parentheses do anything? Or does Python ignore them?

Comment: The parentheses are used to specify superclasses. If you're using the default superclass `object`, they're optional.

Comment: No, when you aren't using inheritance and just creating a class, they don't change anything.

Comment: `class Crawler(): ...` is equivalent to `class Crawler: ...` which is equivalent to `class Crawler(object): ...`

Answer (score 2):

Python ignores them.  They were required in Python 2, and times have changed.

You do use the parenthesis with a super class name to specify that class subclasses another class.  If you do so, the Engineering Manager will come to your desk and ask you to file a TPS report for why you used a subclass.  Remember to add the coversheet.

Comment: As a historical footnote, python they weren't required in python 2 either.  Prior to 2.7, python had what came to be termed "old-style classes" that didn't need parens. Beginning with 2.2, if you inherited from `object` (so parens required) you got "new-style classes". By 2.7, everything was "new-style classes" which are the standard class of 3.x.